# How do I change change the variables of a structure inside an array

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure something out. I've created a new struct called guest:

```
typedef struct guest {
    char guest_name[GUEST_AND_ROOM_NAME_LENGTH];
    int money_left;
    bool is_guest_in_room;
}guest;
```

And I've written a function to initialize the variables of each struct in an array of guest structs. I have initialized the arrays like so:

```
guest *guest_list[MAX_GUESTS_IN_HOTEL];
```

and my function for updating the parameters is:

```
void create_new_guest(char *guest_line_in_file, guest **guest_list, int num_of_guests_in_hotel) 
{
    char *line_ptr = (char*)malloc((strlen(guest_line_in_file)+1) * sizeof(char));
    char *split_string[NUM_OF_PARAMETERS_FOR_GUEST]; 

    strcpy(line_ptr, guest_line_in_file);
    if ((guest_list != NULL)&&(line_ptr!=NULL)) {
        split_string_by_space(line_ptr, split_string);
        strcpy((guest_list[num_of_guests_in_hotel])->guest_name, split_string[0]);
        (guest_list[num_of_guests_in_hotel])->is_guest_in_room = false;
        (guest_list[num_of_guests_in_hotel])->money_left = atoi(split_string[1]);
    }
    else{ 
        printf("Memory allocation of new guest failed! Exiting\n"); 
    }
    free(line_ptr);
    return;
}
```

The call for the function:

```
create_new_guest(current_line_in_file, guest_list, num_of_guests_in_hotel);
```

Where current_line_in_file is a string that contains the input of the variables and is decomposed by split_string_by_space function.

But every time it gets to the part of updating the name of the guest I get:
'Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.'

I know there's something wrong with how I initialize my arrays but I don't quite understand what is it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't provide a way to increment the number of guests in the calling code, so the calling code doesn't realize when you've added a guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1.

`guest_list`, after:

```
  guest *guest_list[MAX_GUESTS_IN_HOTEL];
```

as well as,

`split_string`, after:

```
  char *split_string[NUM_OF_PARAMETERS_FOR_GUEST];
```

are not arrays of the respective datatypes of `guest` and `char`, as you might have intended to do. They are arrays of pointers after these declarations.

Omit the dereference operator `*`:

```
  guest guest_list[MAX_GUESTS_IN_HOTEL];

  char split_string[NUM_OF_PARAMETERS_FOR_GUEST];
```

Also edit the parameter `guest **guest_list` to `guest *guest_list` in the call of `create_new_guest()`. Then test it again.

#### 2.

You shouldn´t use the same identifier for the structure name/tag and a variable of its own:

```
typedef struct guest {
    char guest_name[GUEST_AND_ROOM_NAME_LENGTH];
    int money_left;
    bool is_guest_in_room;
}guest;                           // <- Same Name for variable as structure
```

Even if this is valid in C, it is still bad programming style.
Rather do it like that:

```
typedef struct guest_struct {     // <- Structure tag is different now.
    char guest_name[GUEST_AND_ROOM_NAME_LENGTH];
    int money_left;
    bool is_guest_in_room;
}guest;
```

Technically, it is also allowed to omit a separate structure name/tag by define structures by the use of typedef:

```
typedef struct{     //<- Structure tag is omitted here now.
    char guest_name[GUEST_AND_ROOM_NAME_LENGTH];
    int money_left;
    bool is_guest_in_room;
}guest;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are never allocating memory to store the actual `guest` data structure.

The `guest_list` declaration allocates an array that can hold the given number of pointers.  It does not allocate the memory that the pointers will reference.